# Copy VBA code from one Worksheet to another using VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

Ok here is what I want to accomplish: I am trying to copy all the VBA code from "Sheet2" to "Sheet 3" code pane. I'm NOT referring to copying a Module from one to another but the excel sheet object code.

*I already added a Reference to MS VB for Applications Extensibility 5.3*

I'm not sure where to start but this is what I have started with and its not going anywhere and probably all wrong. Please Help - Simply want to programmatically copy sheet vba code to another sheet vba pane.

```
Dim CodeCopy As VBIDE.CodePane
Set CodeCopy = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet2").VBE
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponenets("Sheet3").CodeModule = CodeCopy
```

Comment: Its a common mis-perception that adding this reference is necessary to work with the VBIDE. You can just use `Dim CodeCopy As Object` etc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `CodeModule` object instead of the `CodePane`, then you can create a second variable to represent the destination module (where you will "paste" the code).

```
Sub test()

Dim CodeCopy As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim CodePaste As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim numLines As Integer

Set CodeCopy = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet2").CodeModule
Set CodePaste = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet3").CodeModule

numLines = CodeCopy.CountOfLines
'Use this line to erase all code that might already be in sheet3:
'If CodePaste.CountOfLines > 1 Then CodePaste.DeleteLines 1, CodePaste.CountOfLines

CodePaste.AddFromString CodeCopy.Lines(1, numLines)
End Sub
```

---

In addition to adding a reference to "*Reference to MS VB for Applications Extensibility 5.3*"

You'll also need to [enable programmatic access](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) to the VBA Project.

> In Excel 2007+, click the Developer item on the main Ribbon and then
>   click the Macro Security item in the Code panel. In that dialog,
>   choose Macro Settings and check the Trust access to the VBA project
>   object model.

Comment: Thanks David - Works perfect and now I know where my mistake was. Now I have another problem with it but my question was very general at first. The worksheet that i'm copying over to is being created by vba code so I will not know what sheet # it is. it's stored as a variable "b" so i have text that im adding to the new sheet as well and i call it as `WorkSheets(b).Cells(4, 3).Value = screenName` but if I try to replace "Sheets3" in `Set codePaste = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Sheet3").CodeModule` over to `b` then it does not work...seems like I have to specify the sheet#. any way??

Comment: by the way, I am going to accept your answer as your original response was perfect.

Comment: Instead of "Sheet3" try `Set CodePaste = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(WorkSheets(b).Name).CodeModule`

Comment: Thanks again David - .Name does not work but .Index works. I'm still running into issues...seems like when I run the code it copies the code from "Sheet2" and pastes it back to "Sheet2" even thought I have `Set CodePaste = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets(b).Index).CodeModule` I also tried `Set CodePaste = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Index).CodeModule` since the new sheet "b" is automatically activated. Nothing seems to work properly, keeps pasting back into the source "Sheet2".

Comment: Is the destination worksheet part of the same (Active) workbook?  If so, try: Set CodePaste = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets(b).CodeName).CodeModule`. As long as `b` is an integer representing the sheet's index, I think that will work.

Comment: just adding this for future reference, because I spent a couple of hours debugging on this. Make sure numOfLines attribute is always > 0, otherwise you get an error.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all!  After testing multiple suggestions above, where "b" is the Worksheet name, you must use `.CodeName`, NOT `.Name`

```
Set CodePaste = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(WorkShe‌ets(b).CodeName).Cod‌​eModule
```

If you have set your target worksheet as an object:

```
Dim T As Worksheet  
Set T = Worksheets("Test")
```

Then you simply need:

```
Set CodePaste = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Worksheets(T.Name).CodeName).Cod‌​eModule
```