# Need to run code of Chart sheet from any other chart sheet module or normal module or any class

Tags: excel, charts, vba

A part of main code is related to chart sheet which  enables a click on a chart(Coding is done in chart sheet ) triggers a macro. But the main program involves deleting and creation of chart sheet. Once the program deletes the Chart sheet, the code in chart sheet also gets deleted. How to execute the chart sheet code when i create a new chart?

```
Sub AddNewChart()
Dim Newchart As Chart, ram As String, ram1 As String, num As Long

num = InputBox("Please Enter the Sheet Number", "Sheet Number")
'To execute code in particular sheet number

ram = Worksheets(num).Range("AY4").End(xlDown).Address(False, False)
ram1 = Worksheets(num).Range("AZ4").End(xlDown).Address(False, False)


Set Newchart = Charts.Add

 With Newchart
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers

     Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
     .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
     Loop

    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
     .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Values"""

     .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets(num).Range("AY4", ram)

    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets(num).Range("AZ4", ram1)


End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets("Ravi").Delete
'*sheet named ravi is deleted along with code*
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Newchart.Name = "Ravi"
'How to get another code in this Ravi Chart sheet module?
Sheets("Ravi").Activate


End Sub
```

Below one is Chartsheet code which is to be present inside chart sheet module even after deletion and replacing.

```
 Sub Chart_mouseup(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, _ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
Dim ElementID As Long, Arg1 As Long, Arg2 As Long
Dim myX As Variant, myY As Double

With ActiveChart
    ' Pass x & y, return ElementID and Args
    .GetChartElement x, y, ElementID, Arg1, Arg2

    ' Did we click over a point or data label?
    If ElementID = xlSeries Or ElementID = xlDataLabel Then
        If Arg2 > 0 Then
            ' Extract x value from array of x values
            myX = WorksheetFunction.Index _
                (.SeriesCollection(Arg1).XValues, Arg2)
            ' Extract y value from array of y values
            myY = WorksheetFunction.Index _
                (.SeriesCollection(Arg1).Values, Arg2)

            ' Display message box with point information
            MsgBox "Series " & Arg1 & vbCrLf _
                & """" & .SeriesCollection(Arg1).Name & """" & vbCrLf _
                & "Point " & Arg2 & vbCrLf _
                & "X = " & myX & vbCrLf _
                & "Y = " & myY
        End If
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Copy the code before deletion and then paste it back into the new sheet.  See if this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24701517/2521004) helps get you started.  It should be the same method for a chart sheet as it is for code behind a regular sheet.

Comment: Thanks @PortlandRunner It helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a separate class module outside of the chart's code module to handle events in any chart, then use other code to link this class to the chart whose events you need to capture.

Essentially you add a class module, and name it `C_ChartEvents`. Include the event code that you've placed in your chart's code module, and in the declarations section (just under `Option Explicit`) insert

```
Public With Events Cht As Chart
```

Then modify the existing code to use Cht_ instead of Chart_ as the prefix for each event procedure's name, e.g.,

```
Sub Cht_MouseUp(ByVal Blah As Blah...)
```

At the top of the code module where you create a new chart, insert:

```
Dim clsChartEvents As New C_ChartEvents
```

After you create the chart (say, after the With `NewChart`/`End With` block) insert:

```
Set clsChartEvents.Cht = NewChart
```

Now NewChart will respond to the events with the procedures in `C_ChartEvents`.

I have written a tutorial, [Chart Events in Microsoft Excel](http://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel/), that has more of the gory details.